Categorical Dependent Variable
Repost:
Hello all, thank you so much for the response. Here I have provided some information.
a. This is clinical data which is around 859 in sample size.
b. It has 11 columns as input features and they are such as the unique read of the genome, is it a bacteria or virus type as well as pathogen reported by the sequencing. It is a mix of categorical and numerical values.
c. The dependent column has 53 unique values (pathogen detected by the hospital) which my model will try to predict.
Again, any recommendation for me on how to approach that.
Previous Post:
I am trying to build machine learning model where the dependent variable is categorical and have more than 60 values. They are not ordinal or follow any rank.
Any recommendation for me on how to approach that.

Hello Ayesha. This thread may interest you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65024/alternatives-to-the-multinomial-logit-model , but have you tried anything so far? If so, where are you stuck? Also, what is your sample size if you've already collected the data? How many observations are there for the less frequent value? 60 values is a lot, and it may require a lot of data to avoid various problems like overfitting. Generally speaking, you should give much more details about your problem and the nature of your data.

I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question was about alternatives to multinomila logistic, but not specifically about the issue of a large number of levels of the DV.

How to approach this?  I'd say "very, very cautiously, especially if you don't have a huge sample."
First, I'd think very carefully about whether and why you need 60 levels of the dependent variable. (It would help if you said what this was). There could be cases where you really need this, but it may be possible (and even beneficial) to combine some.
Then, I'd be careful to not jump to conclusions based on results, but to be sure to use some form of validation, such as splitting the data into train, test, and validate. Overfitting seems to be very possible.
If you add more details to your question (not just a reply to this answer) then maybe I or someone else will be able to supply more detailed answers.

And when a question is too hard to answer we sometimes must ask a simpler question, for example predicting a projection of the 60 categories along some continuous metric that connects them.  Otherwise the needed sample size will be such that the least frequent category has > 50 observations.
